# How do I see data in CloudKit container for Apple ID account other than developer account?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, apple-id, ckcontainer

I am working on an Xcode project for an iOS app that uses CloudKit. I am able to see the data in the CloudKit container in CloudKit Dashboard when I am logged in to the developer account that Xcode is logged into. When I log into CloudKit Dashboard using a different account that I use on an actual device with the iOS app installed, I am not able to see the container. With another Apple ID account, it says that the account is not registered as a developer account and needs to be registered. It seems to me CloudKit Dashboard should show a container for that app, but it doesn't. Why is this? How do I check the data in CloudKit for an Apple ID that is not the developer account?

Comment: You can't. That data is private to the user (it is in their iCloud Drive).

Comment: @Paulw11 I want to be able to view that data as that user -- using that user's Apple ID. I would be the user looking at my own data. The Apple ID is my own. Is that possible for the user to look at his own private data?

Comment: You can only use the CloudKit console as a developer. Users don't have access. If you want to see user data then you need to log in to iCloud on the device as the developer user

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok. I was afraid of that. So you are saying when I log in as the developer I can only see the data for that specific developer account. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct because you only have access to your own iCloud  drive data.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to be able to see all app data for all users, you'll have to store your data in the **Public Database** of your CloudKit container.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Ok. I'll try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot view the contents of the private database of any user except for the developer's Apple ID (with the exception of the shared database acting as a window into another's private database). To view the contents of other people's private databases, you would have to have their device fetch the data and either store it in the public database or create a shared database (CKShare) with your developer Apple ID.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.